# How to know whether a CMIS property is modifiable?

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis

I know how to read the properties of a CMIS Document.

But how to tell which property is modifiable, which property is read-only?
Using OpenCMIS/DotCMIS.

For instance, CMIS Workbench seems to know, because in its Property Editor, it only lists the field `cmis:name`, and not the other fields (like `cmis:id`).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PropertyDefinition object gives the updatability of a property. With OpenCMIS, you can retrieve "cmis:name" updatability like this :

```
TypeDefinition typeDef = session.getTypeDefinition("cmis:document");
Map<String,PropertyDefinition<?>> propertyDefs = typeDef.getPropertyDefinitions();
PropertyDefinition namePropertyDef = propertyDefs.get("cmis:name");
Updatability nameUpdatability = namePropertyDef.getUpdatability();

if (Updatability.READONLY.equals(nameUpdatability)
    throw new Exception("This field can not be upated");
```

You can have a look on [OpenCMIS javadoc](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.8.0/maven/apidocs/) for details about updatability values